# First-line paragraph indenting in PDFs using R Markdown

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

I'm hoping this is a question with a simple answer. I am using Rmarkdown/knitr to author a PDF document (in RStudio). Many LaTeX classes (like article) automatically indent the first line of a paragraph of text, but Rmarkdown does not, nor can I figure out a way to do so.

Here's a simple example:

```
---
title: "minimal"
author: "prison rodeo"
output: pdf_document  
---

This is an R Markdown document. 

I would like this paragraph to be first-line indented, but it is not.
```

Using > indents the entire paragraph, which is not what I'm looking for. I've tried spaces/tabs at the beginning of each paragraph, and using \indent; neither seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `\setlength\parindent{24pt}` at the start (before This is an...) from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45501/how-to-add-indentation

Comment: That did it! Thanks. If there's a more Rmd-"correct" way to do this, I'd be happy to hear about it as well.

Comment: Im sure there will be, and hopefully someone will show how. That said i tend to hack these things together like this

Comment: Adding `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` at the beginning of a paragraph will indent that first line by 5 spaces. If you're always going to target PDF, the latex solutions are far better.

Comment: @hrbrmstr couldn't you solve this with CSS instead of hardcoding a lot of spaces? For instance, the `text-indent` property specifies the indentation of the first line in a text-block.

Answer (score 30):

The default Pandoc template includes an `indent` argument. If set to `true`, paragraphs start with an indentation.

```
----
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
output: pdf_document
indent: true
----
```

Comment: This is by far the best solution. Also I find it weird that indentation is not enabled by default.

Comment: This works great. Except there is no indent for the first paragraph. Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out. Add `- \usepackage{indentfirst}` to the YAML

Comment: Make sure to add `- \usepackage{indentfirst}` under the `header-includes:` key in the YAML.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the following in your YAML header will work the same and has the advantage of still compiling should you decide to knit your document to an HTML file (though, I haven't tested this).

```
----
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
header-includes:
   - \setlength\parindent{24pt}
output:
    pdf_document
----
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you're after happens to be the default settings in other regards as well, you might also be interested in setting the `\parskip` option to its default setting, since it is otherwise set to `{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}`

```
header-includes:
   - \setlength\parindent{24pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0.0pt plus 1.0pt}
```