# How can i indent the first line only of a paragraph in R markdown?

Tags: r-markdown, indentation, paragraph

I am writing my thesis in R Markdown and knitting either an an HTML or word document and i want to indent only the first line in each paragraph. Is there a way to do it?

I've tried 'indent' true' in the YAML but it did not work

here is the YAML header:

```
bibliography: references.bib
output:
  html_document:
    code_folding: show
    toc: true
    theme: journal
    fig_caption: true
    df_print: paged
    number_sections: true
    indent: true
  word_document:
    toc: true
    indent: true
link-citations: true
csl: nature.csl
biblio-style: nature
```

Comment: See question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460112/first-line-paragraph-indenting-in-pdfs-using-r-markdown

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First-line paragraph indenting in PDFs using R Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460112/first-line-paragraph-indenting-in-pdfs-using-r-markdown)