# Do not indent the first paragraph of a new section

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

I would like to indent every paragraph but the first paragraph of every section in my article. The Rmd file has a `pdf_output` and it is referencing child files containing the sections of my article.

This is what I have:

````
---
bibliography: bibliography.bib
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \setlength{\parskip}{12pt}
  #- \setlength{\parindent}{30pt}
fontsize: 12pt
indent: true
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
```

```{r 01_Introduction, child = here::here("WriteUp", "Child", "Introduction.Rmd")}
```

\newpage
# References
````

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to **indent every paragraph but the first** paragraph of **every section** in my article.

You use `indent` in the YAML. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48338382/5861244).

Here is an example. First the main file:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "me"
date: "11/3/2020"
output: pdf_document
indent: true
---

```{r, child=c('sec1.Rmd', 'sec2.Rmd')}
```
````

Here is the `sec1.Rmd` file:

```
## My section 

Some text.

Some more text.
```

and here is the `sec2.Rmd` file:

```
# That other section

Even more text. 

And the last line.
```

The result is:

[image]

#### Update

It is still indented after I have added:

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \setlength{\parskip}{12pt}
```

to the YAML.

Comment: The first paragraph is still indented.

Comment: In my example, I have "_indent[ed] every paragraph but the first paragraph of every section_"?